# php preg_replace fo danish char's

Tags: php, preg-replace

I did search a lot for this but not come to anything that works

### Case:

I have a php page that show delivery info from a pizza delivery, everything works except the special danish char's: æ, ø and å and their capital counteparts Æ. Ø and Å

they come out ok on screen but on a serial thermal printer they do not and i want to replace these 3 char's with the code that tell the printer what to print.

To make it hard these 3 can show up anywhere INSIDE a word, one example is my streetname: Sandkæret followed by house no. The streetname could also be 2 words.

I can get the replace to work if these char's are on their own, but not if they are inside a word.

So far i have used:

```
$string = $row['delivery_street_address'];

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '*å*';
$patterns[1] = '*æ*';
$patterns[2] = '*ø*';


$replacements = array();
$replacements[3] = '/x7D';
$replacements[2] = 'X';
$replacements[1] = '/x7C';


echo str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

also tried this one:

```
echo preg_replace("/([æ])/", "<span class=\"initial\">$1</span>", $string);
```

but still no go

could a kind soul help out a NOOB + Newbie ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_replace` will work fine, just remove the `*`'s around the characters:

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = 'å';
$patterns[1] = 'æ';
$patterns[2] = 'ø';
```

Of course, you could also write it like this:

```
$patterns = array('å', 'æ', 'ø');
$replacements = array('/x7D', 'X', '/x7C');
echo str_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Comment: I did try without the * but then i got the delimiter error, but will give it another whot

Comment: @user3434356 `preg_replace` will throw that error (see [Delimiters](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)), but for `str_replace`, they are interpreted literally -- i.e. it will look for strings like `'foo*å*bar'`.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `str_replace` with `preg_replace` would work. Or @p.s.w.g's answer would work as well :)